# How can i print an interior supply of structure on c?

Tags: c, struct, printf

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct game{
  bool is_computer_game;
  bool  is_tabletop_game;
  bool is_for_children;
  bool is_collective;
};

int main(){
  int n,a,b,c,d;
  printf("How much games do you want?:");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  struct game games[n];
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    a=rand()%2;
    b=1-a;
    c=rand()%2;
    d=rand()%2;
      if(a==0){
            games[i].is_computer_game=false;
      }
      if(a==1){
            games[i].is_computer_game=true;
      }
      if(b==0){
            games[i].is_tabletop_game=false;
      }
      if(b==1){
            games[i].is_tabletop_game=true;
      }
      if(c==0){
            games[i].is_for_children=false;
      }
      if(c==1){
            games[i].is_for_children=true;
      }
      if(d==0){
            games[i].is_collective=false;
      }
      if(d==1){
            games[i].is_collective=true;
      }

  }
  printf("\nHere is the information about all games we have:\n\n ");
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("is the game a computer one: %d\n",games[i].is_computer_game);
    printf("is the game a tabletop one: %d\n",games[i].is_tabletop_game);
    printf("is the game for children: %d\n",games[i].is_for_children);
    printf("is the game a collective one: %d\n\n",games[i].is_collective);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Well, i have this code that makes a structure and fills it with some elements and print all of them. another thing is that this program must also print an intrerior supply of it. To cut a long story short, i need that

```
struct game games[n]
```

was printed as in the code and as a string of binary numbers but i have no idea how can i do this. can you help me with it?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, but if you just want to print the raw contents of your `games` array as hexadecimal values, you can do something like this: `char *ptr = (char*)games; for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(games); ++i) printf(" %02X",ptr[i]);`

Comment: BTW, since boolean values in C are just 0 and 1, your `if` statements are not necessary and you can just do a direct assignment, such as `games[i].is_computer_game = a;`

Comment: SGeorgiades,well that this structure consists only of zeros and ones, your suggestion is truly correct. thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line in your code as follows:

```
int n,a,b,c,d,i;
```

Then add the following block before the `return 0;` of `main()`:

```
char *ptr = (char*)games;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(games); ++i) printf(" %02X",ptr[i]);   /* Option 1 */
printf("\n");

for (i = 0; i < sizeof(games); i+=4) 
printf("%1X%1X%1X%1X",ptr[i],ptr[i+1],ptr[i+2],ptr[i+3]);     /* Option 2 */
```

Run your code, give input 3 for n. You should see something like the following output:

```
How much games do you want?:3
Here is the information about all games we have:

 is the game a computer one: 1
is the game a tabletop one: 0
is the game for children: 0
is the game a collective one: 1

is the game a computer one: 1
is the game a tabletop one: 0
is the game for children: 1
is the game a collective one: 1

is the game a computer one: 0
is the game a tabletop one: 1
is the game for children: 0
is the game a collective one: 1

 01 00 00 01 01 00 01 01 00 01 00 01           /* Option 1 */
 1001 1011 0101                                /* Option 2 */
```

You could determine whether you prefer Option 1 or Option 2.